# Comparing columns in SAS using proc import with optional new columns

Tags: import, sas, proc

I am a SAS beginner and a couple of years ago, I have written a program where I proc import 2 excel sheets and compare columns against each other. Excel 1 has standard columns, excel 2 , which are several tabs,  they have added 2 more similar columns for each tab,  and now my program should do the comparing of columns based on the added 2 new columns , but, it should also work if it cannot detect those two columns as we also have people using the excel sheet without the 2 new columns.

Can you please suggest on how to proceed, thank you

I tried %varexist, but, somehow, I am not able to come up with an idea of how the comparison will work if I ask it to compare in the event of no 2 new columns

Comment: Show how you are comparing now.  What do you want to differently for the new columns?  Note that PROC COMPARE will work fine if one dataset has 2 variables that the other dataset does not.  Obviously it cannot compare the new variables to something that does not exist, but if both datasets have the new variables they will be compared.

Answer (score 0):

In the code below, replace 'ColumnA' and 'ColumnB' with the names of the two additional columns. If the columns exist, you can perform the comparison using the additional columns. You can use the PROC COMPARE procedure or write custom code to compare the required columns. Otherwise, you need to compare the standard columns without considering the additional columns.

```
/* Step 1: Import the two Excel sheets */
proc import datafile='path_to_excel1.xlsx' out=Sheet1 dbms=xlsx replace;
  sheet='Sheet1';
  getnames=yes;
run;

proc import datafile='path_to_excel2.xlsx' out=Sheet2 dbms=xlsx replace;
  sheet='Sheet1';
  getnames=yes;
run;

/* Step 2: Check if the required columns exist in Sheet2 */
proc contents data=Sheet2 out=Sheet2_contents noprint;
run;

data _null_;
  set Sheet2_contents;
  where libname='WORK' and memname='SHEET2' and (name='ColumnA' or name='ColumnB');
  if _n_ > 0 then call symputx('columns_exist', 'YES');
run;

/* Step 3: Compare the columns based on the existence of the additional columns */
%macro perform_comparison;
  %if %symexist(columns_exist) %then %do;
    /* Columns exist, perform comparison with additional columns */
    /* Your comparison logic here */
    /* You can use PROC COMPARE or custom code */
  %end;
  %else %do;
    /* Columns do not exist, perform comparison without additional columns */
    /* Your comparison logic here */
    /* You can use PROC COMPARE or custom code */
  %end;
%mend;

/* Call the macro to perform the comparison */
%perform_comparison;
```